# incompatibility between node 18.17.1 and npm 9.6.7

Tags: node.js, npm

If I refer to the official site https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases

[compatibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P10lj.jpg)

I must not have any incompatibility.

Except that I have this error message, which tells me the opposite.

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYNCk.jpg)

Can someone explain to me?!

Could nvm (version 1.1.7) be the cause?!

i uninstalled node and installed it again. However during the installation it specifies that it installs npm 9.6.7 !!

But same problem.

Comment: You can try to update npm . `npm i -g npm`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if i do npm i -g npm, j'aurai la même erreur : ERROR: npm v9.6.7 is known not to run on Node.js v18.17.1.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.

Comment: Problem solved. it was nvm version problem. I updated NVM to version 1.1.11. I uninstalled node and installed it again, via nvm of course!